# Function in a python class that is not a method

Tags: python-2.7

I have a class that needs auxiliary functions, e.g. one to calculate a checksum that just uses the passed in arguments and not any properties of the class. This function is only called by the class's methods. So I dont need to pass in the 'self' as the first formal of the function.

How should I implement these functions? Can I have non-method functions in a class? Should I define them outside the class (even though they are not used by anything else)? Or is it ok for them to be regular methods?

Comment: What's so bad about adding the self parameter and simply not using it? Why you do you hate your self?

Comment: @yuvi :-) Yes fair enough, I just though it might be bad practice or something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a function inside a class that doesn't take self as an argument, use the `@staticmethod` decorator:

```
 class Awesomeness(object):
     def method(self, *args):
         pass

     @staticmethod
     def another_method(*args):
         pass
```

However, from a conceptual standpoint I would definitely consider putting it at module scope, especially if it's a checksum function that doesn't use instance or class properties.

Comment: @spiderplant0: *Module scope* is essentially another way of saying *global*. It was one of the options you brought up yourself, of defining the function "outside the class".

Answer (score 4):

Just do a nested function:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, arg):
        def inner(arg):
            print 'Yo Adrian imma in inner with {}!'.format(arg)

        inner(arg)    

Foo().bar('argument')
```

Or just ignore the `self`:

```
class Foo(object):

    def prive(_, arg):
        print 'In prive with {}!'.format(arg)


    def bar(self, arg):
        def inner(arg):
            print 'Yo Adrian imma in inner with {}!'.format(arg)

        inner(arg)   
        self.prive(arg)

    def foo(self,arg):
        self.prive(arg)     

Foo().bar('argument')
Foo().foo('another argument')
```

Second example prints:

```
Yo Adrian imma in inner with argument!   
In prive with argument!
In prive with another argument!
```

Comment: Unfortunately the asker implies that it is used by multiple methods.

Comment: Wanted to define a callback function inside a class, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

tldr define a function outside the class

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        myfunc()

def myfunc():
    print('f')

myclass() # prints f
```

from best to worst:

1. define outside the class
2. use staticmethod decorator
3. define a method, but ignore self

the disadvantage of 2 & 3 is that the "function" is still a method as it can applied to an object the regular way: self.myfunc()